# Delete confirmation message in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get confirmation message before deleting the data, and also I would like to  maintain my data in database while deleting  them in frontend .
here is my (project) index.php view

```
 <div class="main-sec-contant">
<div class="ProjectsDetails">
    <h2 class="heading">Projects Details</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table id="table_id" class="display">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Project Name</th>
                        <th>Client Name</th>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>Project Manager</th>
                        <th>Support Staff</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                foreach($project as $n)
                {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $n->project_name;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $n->client_name;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $n->company;?></td>
                        <td><a class="pro-circle"><img class="img-sm" src="<?php echo site_url('assets/image/man.png');?>"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="<?php echo $n-> project_manager;?>" data-original-title="Click to deactivate the user"></a>&nbsp&nbsp </td>
                        <td><a class="pro-circle"><img class="img-sm" src="<?php echo site_url('assets/image/man.png');?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="<?php echo $n-> support_staff;?>" data-original-title="Click to deactivate the user"></a>&nbsp&nbsp 
                        <a class="pro-circle"><img class="img-sm" src="<?php echo site_url('assets/image/man.png');?>"></a>&nbsp&nbsp
                      <a class="pro-circle"><img class="img-sm" src="<?php echo site_url('assets/image/man.png');?>"></a></td>
                        <td><span class="icoact"></span> Active</td>
                        <td><a class="edit" href="<?php echo site_url('admin/project/edit/'.$n->id);?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" ></i></a>&nbsp&nbsp<a class="delete"  href="<?php echo site_url('admin/project/delete/'.$n->id);?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Project.php controller

```
public function index ()
{
  $data['company_name'] = $this->project_model->getAllCompanyName();
  $data['project'] = $this->project_model->getProjectDetails();
  $this->load->view('admin/project/index',$data);

}
function delete($id)
 {
   $this->project_model->delete($id); 
   $this->session->set_flashdata ('success','Project Deleted Sucessfully');
   redirect('admin/project/index');

 }
```

And here is my Project_model.php , delete function

```
 function getProjectDetails()
 {
//table  (projects)

 $delete_flag=0;
 $data['project'] = $this->db->get_where('projects',array('delete_flag!='=>$delete_flag))->result_array();
```

}

```
function getById($id)
 {
   return $this->db->get_where('projects',array('id'=>$id))->row();

 }

function delete($id)
 {
  $delete_flag=0;
  $this->db->where('id',$id)->update('projects',array('delete_flag'=>$delete_flag));
    
 }
```

Right now I am able to delete the data successfully from both frontend and database, I would appreciate if you can help me how I can  get the confirmation message, and also maintain my data in database while deleting them from frontend ?

Here is the database table

[image]

Comment: you want to show confirm message before deleteing the record?

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Delete in Frontend only:**

Add a boolean Column "delete_flag" to your project database table and update it to TRUE when delete is clicked in frontend.

Then change your load Method in Project model to only get Projects where delete_flag = 0

**Delete Confirmation:**

Search for Modal Dialog. You can easily set up a message and confirm button link with a modal Dialog. Maybe you are even using a Template which already provides it.

See an example here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: I just updated my code according your recommendation for maintaining data in database,its not working , can you please check

Comment: I actually couldent get what you mean by updating to TRUE, maybe thats the problem , would appreciate if you can provide me the code

Comment: Just set the value to 1 like this `$this->db->where('id',$id)->update('projects',array('delete_flag'=>1));`

Comment: not working , i am getting errors:Undefined variable: id in project_model.php ,  and Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in view

Answer (score 0):

**For Data Delete from Frontend only but not from database:-**

You should add a Column name `delete_flag` int datatype to your project database table and update it to `0`, while deleting the record.

**Data Delete Confirmation Alert Message:-**

```
<td><a class="delete"  href="<?php echo site_url('admin/project/delete/'.$n->id);?>"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to Delete this Record?')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
```

**controller Code Project.php :-**

```
function delete($id)
{
   $this->project_model->delete($id); 
   $this->session->set_flashdata ('success','Project Deleted Sucessfully');
   redirect('admin/project/index');

}
```

**Model Code Project_model.php :-**

```
function getProjectDetails()
{
$delete_flag=0;
   $data['project'] = $this->db->get_where('projects',array('delete_flag!='=>$delete_flag))->result_array();
}


    function delete($id)
    {
          $delete_flag=0;
          $this->db->where('id',$id)->update('projects',array('delete_flag'=>$delete_flag));
        
    }
```

**In Your View:-**

Show Only records which have `delete_flag!=0` by this query in your  `getProjectDetails()`

Comment: i followed your answer, i am getting confirmation message , but delete function is not working anymore

Comment: Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: project/index.php

Line Number: 51

Backtrace:

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/ASGB/application/views/admin/project/index.php
Line: 51
Function: _error_handler

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/ASGB/application/controllers/admin/Project.php
Line: 16
Function: view

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/ASGB/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: I  tried to add new project and see what is the  delete_flag value in database before deleting  and it is 0

Comment: Now change your getProjectDetails() in Model with updated answer.

Comment: Still getting same errors, please check updated code of mine

Comment: Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: project/index.php

Line Number: 51

Backtrace:

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/ASGB/application/views/admin/project/index.php
Line: 51
Function: _error_handler

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/ASGB/application/controllers/admin/Project.php
Line: 16
Function: view

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/ASGB/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: see what you get in  `print_r($data['project']); die();` ???

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data.                                                                                         A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Filename: admin/Project.php.      getting these two errors line 14 is :print_r($data['project']); die();

Comment: I also ran print_r($_REQUEST);
          die;                 and I am getting empty array

Comment: Solved , thanks for your help ,just  please change the result_array(); to only result(); that was the issue